# DFA + counter with multiplication, addition, brackets

Tags: math, computation-theory, dfa, deterministic

I'm looking at an exam question which says

'Explain how a correctly formed arithmetic expression over variables a, b, c that contains additions, multiplication and brackets can be recognised by a DFA with a counter. (Such a DFA can increment and decrement the counter on each transition as well as test it for zero).'

I'm not quite sure I understand what it's actually asking. If someone could provide a hint that would be greatly appreciated. (i.e. what the multiplication of a and b would be for example)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to programming directly! This *maybe* a better fit for CS Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is just a ***hint***, then I think this should be enough:

1. Some strings represent valid arithmetic expressions such as

```
a + b
(a + b)*(c + d)
```

and some are invalid such as

```
a + - b
a b
)
()
(a + b)*)c+d(
```

2. "*can be recognised by a DFA with a counter*"  here means that you can build a [Deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) such that it stops at one of the "accept states" after processing a sting if and only if that string represents a valid arithmetic expression

P.S. Additional hint: the counting part is important here because a simple DFA can't even recognize whether an arbitrary string of brackets is properly matched.

Comment: So would it just be a DFA such that each transition adds to the expression, from the alphabet of a,b,c,+,*,(,), and each time an open bracket is read, the counter is incremented, and when the closed bracket is read it is decremented, and only when it is 0 does it accept an input?

Comment: @SonyaArnolds, It is correct general direction but that's not enough. Look closer at my invalid examples. Some of them will be accepted by your DFA.